# Quiet output from pip via requirements file?

Tags: pip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, requirements.txt

pip has a -q/--quiet flag that works ideally from the command line.  I'm using an automated deployment process (Amazon Elastic Beanstalk), and the tools use pip to install from a requirements file.

Unfortunately, pip is generating non-error output that's causing EB to abort due to its logger being unable to handle non-ASCII output.

Since I can't apply the quiet flag to the pip command directly (it's run automatically), is there a per-line flag I can set in my requirements file or an environment variable that would suppress pip's output?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After more digging, this is a pending feature request for pip in github:

https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/271

Temporary workaround: Using a separate bash script to invoke pip per-line until this is implemented, published, and available on Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: To summarize so others don't have to chase this down, as of today, `pip` will take a `-q` option to quiet installation from requirements files, i.e. `pip -q install -r requirements.txt` - works great!  Pip also supports per-line --global-option="..." and --install-option=".." inside the requirements file, depending on whether you want your option to be inserted before or after the 'install' on the setup.py line, e.g. `python <global_opt> install <install_option> setup.py`.   See https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/2537

Comment: sadly, pip does not implement a quiet option, as this post correctly identifies. passing `-q` still causes non-error output.

Answer (score 40):

Pip offers the `--quiet / -q` option to silence output. Example:

`pip install -q -r requirements.txt`

Comment: The question starts with "pip has a -q/--quiet flag..."

Comment: Looks like I only read the Question Title + the answers. And it looks like several others did as well and found my response helpful.